# Loop not running when its method to run it is called

Tags: c#, class, loops, console-application

If I call the default constructor "Creature" in main and then try to call the method "Generate Creator" the loop never runs.  If I did a normal for loop it throws out of bounds errors even knowing the default constructor sets the length of the array.  It is probably a dumb error I am not seeing. (this isnt all of the code)

```
        class Creature
        {
           static int geneLength;
           byte[] Chromosome = new byte[geneLength];
           int fitness;

           string geneString;
           Random rn = new Random();

           public Creature()
           {
              geneLength = 36;
              fitness = 0;
           }

           public void GenerateCreature()
           {
              foreach(byte g in Chromosome)
              {
               Chromosome[g] = (byte)rn.Next(0, 2);
               geneString += Chromosome[g].ToString();
              }
           }
        }
```

Main:

```
       namespace Creature_Generator
       {
          class Program
          {
             static void Main(string[] args)
             {
                Creature c = new Creature();

                c.GenerateCreature();
                Console.WriteLine(c.getGeneString);

             }
          } 
       }
```

Comment: Try making creature class public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(byte g in Chromosome)
{
    Chromosome[g] = (byte)rn.Next(0, 2); // 'g' is not an index
    geneString += Chromosome[g].ToString(); // 'g' is not an index
}
```

while you are using `foreach (byte g in Chromosome)`, I believe it is not a proper way to use code like `Chromosome[g]` which g is suppose a `value` not an `index`

try

```
StringBuilder geneString = new StringBuilder();
public Creature()
{
    geneLength = 36;
    this.Chromosome = new byte[geneLength];
    fitness = 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < this.Chromosome.Length; i++)
{
    byte g = this.Chromosome[i]; // this line is useless
    this.Chromosome[i] = (byte)rn.Next(0, 2);
    geneString.Append(this.Chromosome[i].ToString());
}
```

Plus, if you are hard-coding geneLength = 36 in the constructor, consider use `public int geneString { get; private set;}` instead of `static int geneLength;` or

```
static int _geneLength = 36;
public int geneLength { get; private set; }

public Creature() { this.geneLength = _geneLength; }
public Creature(int geneLength) { this.geneLength = geneLength; }
```

### Edit 1 -

According to @moreON advice, `string geneString` is modified from class `string` to `StringBuilder`, read more on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You probably don't need `byte g = this.Chromosome[i];` anymore =]

Comment: Normally when you getting 'out of bounds' means you are looking at an index of an array, that the index is not available, like looking `Chromosome[g]` and the `g` maybe equal to 10000 and turns your line into `Chromosome[10000]`. `foreach (byte g in Chromosome)` means getting each value from Chromosome and assign to g, so the g may be 10000 or 20000 and your Chromosome is containing just 36 elements... It is expected to throw such exception

Comment: Ok, so my issue with the out of bounds error I because is was doing     `for (int i = 0; i <= this.Chromosome.Length; i++)` instead of `for (int i = 0; i < this.Chromosome.Length; i++)` .  Why was the `<=` screwing it up?

Comment: @sydluce All array in most programming language starts at index [0] , while you have an array with size 36, the maximum of it will be Arr[35], so when you use <= Arr.Length, the last index will be Arr[36] which is out of bounds

Comment: @ZayLau I'm an idiot, I wasn't thinking about that when I was putting Arr.length in there because every other time I always put `arr.length - 1` and this time I just missed that. haha  Thank you for your help!

Comment: The JIT might pick up on the repeated string concatenation and optimise it away, but it's generally nicer to explicitly do something that you know won't be run in quadratic time where possible. eg. use a StringBuilder to build geneString instead of concatenation. Even for small examples, this really doesn't add anything hard to understand to the code, and might help someone pick up some good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Other than your issue attempting to use the results of foreach to index an array, as others have mentioned, you're also ignoring the order in which initialisers and constructors are executed.

If we ignore inheritance (because you have none that is interesting here). Initializers are run before constructors.

This means that you are creating the array Chromosome before assigning 36 to geneLength. This means that geneLength was still default(int), which is 0, so you created an array with length 0.

For more on c# constructors see Jon Skeet's excellent page: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/constructors.html

geneLength should probably also not be static, but that's a different discussion.

Comment: I tried doing the for each because I kept getting out of bounds errors with the for loop and my issue was I was doing `for (int i = 0; i <= this.Chromosome.Length; i++);` and the `<=` was screwing it up. And I just wasn't thinking when I was declaring the array before assigning its length.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `geneLength` to be a `static` field then you need to initialize it with a `static` constructor. Otherwise the value of `geneLength` is still `0` at the moment you instantiate the class.

Write your code like this instead:

```
class Creature
{
    static int geneLength;
    byte[] Chromosome = new byte[geneLength];
    int fitness;

    string geneString;
    Random rn = new Random();

    static Creature()
    {
        geneLength = 36;
    }

    public Creature()
    {
        fitness = 0;
    }

    public void GenerateCreature()
    {
        foreach (byte g in Chromosome)
        {
            Chromosome[g] = (byte)rn.Next(0, 2);
            geneString += Chromosome[g].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```